# How can Apache Camel be used to monitor file changes?

Tags: file, apache-camel

I would like to monitor all of the files in a given directory for changes, ie an updated timestamp. This use case seems natural for Camel using the file component, but I can't seem to find a way to configure this behavior.

A uri like:

```
file:/some/directory
```

will consume the files in the provided directory but will delete them.

A uri like:

```
file:/some/directory?noop=true
```

consumes each file once when it is added or when the route is started.

It's surprising that there isn't an option along the lines of

```
consumeOnChange=true
```

Is there a straightforward way to monitor file changes and not delete the file after consuming?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this by setting up the idempotentKey to tell Camel how a file is considered changed. For example if the file size changes, or its timestamp changes etc.

See more details at the Camel file documentation at: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html

See the section *Avoiding reading the same file more than once (idempotent consumer)*. And read about idempotent and idempotentKey.

So something alike

```
from("file:/somedir?noop=true&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:size}")
```

Or

```
from("file:/somedir?noop=true&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:modified}")
```

You can read here about the various ${file:xxx} tokens you can use: http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, Claus. I really appreciate your work on Camel. I just tried this for 20 minutes before my next meeting and I can't seem to get it working. I tried with size and modified to no avail. I now understand that noop turns idempotent true by default which makes sense. I'll keep looking at the file tokens when I have a bit more time, but I expected it to start picking up modified files when I added ${file:name}-${file:modified}. Is there more to it? Thanks again!

Comment: Ah just remembered I fixed a bug recently with idempotentKey, though reported against FTP. Its CAMEL-6936. So will be fixed in upcoming releases. Sorry for that bug.

Comment: no worries - so a url like the second one you posted should work on a future release? Are SNAPSHOT artifacts published anywhere?

Comment: Hmm - I tried the latest 2.12.2-SNAPSHOT and 2.13-SNAPSHOT. No luck. To be clear, my url now looks like " ?noop=true&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:modified} Maybe it's not in the builds yet?

Comment: Ah thanks the first fix from CAMEL-6936 didn't cover it all. I have fixed this again. So any future SNAPSHOT updates should include the fix.

Comment: Still no luck on the current SNAPSHOTs - should this feature be working now?

Comment: Thanks for this post, I also need it.  On the size vs modified, I will use modified since size might the same but different content like "message a" to "message b" would be missed in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Setting *noop* to **true** will result in Camel setting *idempotent=true* as well, despite the fact that *idempotent* is **false** by default.

Simplest solution to monitor files would be:

```
.from("file:path?noop=true&idempotent=false&delay=60s")
```

This will monitor changes to all files in the given directory every one minute.

This can be found in the Camel documentation at: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Camel supports that specific feature but with the existent options you can come up with a similar solution of monitoring a directory.

What you need to do is set a small delay value to check the directory and maintain a repository of the already read files. Depending on how you configure the repository (by size, by filename, by a mix of them...) this solution would be able to provide you information about news files and modified files. As a caveat it would be consuming the files in the directory very often.

Maybe you could use other solutions different from Camel like Apache Commons VFS2 (I wrote a explanation about how to use it for this scenario: [WatchService locks some files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017861/watchservice-locks-some-files/20019953#20019953)

Comment: Well said. This is the pragmatic answer :-)
In my case (a Camel FTP client shipping files as soon as they're made available) I added a JMS queue where the file producer posts a message that wakes up the FTP client.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem i.e. wanted to copy updated files also (along with new files). Below is my configuration,

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {

    CamelContext cc = new DefaultCamelContext();

    cc.addRoutes(createRouteBuilder());

    cc.start();

    Thread.sleep(10 * 60 * 1000);

    cc.stop();
}


protected static RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("file://D:/Production"
                    + "?idempotent=true"
                    + "&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:size}"
                    + "&include=.*.log"
                    + "&noop=true"
                    + "&readLock=changed")

            .to("file://D:/LogRepository");
        }
    };
}
```

My testing steps:

1. Run the program and it copies few .log files from D:/Production to D:/LogRepository and then continues to poll D:/Production directory
2. I opened a already copied log say A.log from D:/Production (since noop=true nothing is moved) and edited it with some editor tool. This doubled the file size and save it.

At this point I think Camel is supposed to copy that particular file again since its size is modified and in my route definition I used "**idempotent=true&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:size}&readLock=changed**". But camel ignores the file.
When I use TRACE for logging it says "Skipping as file is already in progress...", but I did not find any lock file in D:/Production directory when I editted and saved the file.

I also checked that camel still ignores the file if I replace A.log (with same name but bigger size) in D:/Production directory from outside.

But I found, **everything is working as expected if I remove noop=true option**.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you ever try posting this as a separate question?

Comment: Is there any flag to trigger the route when from a watched folder a file is deleted instead of modified?

Answer (score 1):

If you want monitor file changes in camel, use file-watch component.

Example -> RECURSIVE WATCH ALL EVENTS (FILE CREATION, FILE DELETION, FILE MODIFICATION):

```
from("file-watch://some-directory")
.log("File event: ${header.CamelFileEventType} occurred on file ${header.CamelFileName} at ${header.CamelFileLastModified}");
```

You can see the complete documentation here:
[Camel file-watch component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-watch-component.html)