# How to listen file modifications in spring-camel?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am novice in spring-camel and apache camel overall
I've read http://camel.apache.org/file.html
and I want to listen file modifications.

Thus I wrote:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    from("file:feed.txt")
            .log("msg: ${body}")
            .process(exchange -> {
                System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
            });
}
```

`init` method is invoked on startup but process callback is not invoked.

I tried to add new lines into the file after startup but nothing happens.
Also I am sure that application sees the file because it logs on startup:

```
2017-10-24 15:26:13.421  INFO 10620 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route1 started and consuming from: file://feed.txt
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: Which version of apache-camel do you use? The link you provided is for 1.x.x however the actual version is something like 2.x.x

Comment: @Oleg, I use camel-core-2.20.0.jar

Comment: You can try to arrange it using `idempotentKey` as described in this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086532/how-can-apache-camel-be-used-to-monitor-file-changes

Comment: @Oleg but as I wrote in answer - camel moves files after processing

Comment: In order to leave them at the same place, specify `noop=true`.

Comment: Look at the beginner examples to see how they start and run Camel: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Oleg Kurbatov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497060/oleg-kurbatov)

The correct link:

http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/file2.html

I created directory `feed` instead of file `feed.txt`

and put several files there. Then I started app and `Camel` read it, `Camel` moved my files into `.camel` directory. Also tried to put file dinamycally. I put file into `feed` folder and `Camel` read it successfully.